# how to clear url's on second level subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've a website and it has subfolders (contents). i'm clearing extensions via .htaccess:

http://example.com/k/page.php to
http://example.com/k/page

now i've another subfolder:

http://example.com/e/k/page.php

and want to use it as http://example.com/e/k/page

but my htaccess doesn't allow me to do it.

here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

how can i do that? i've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)//([^/]+)$ /$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

it worked on /e/k/page thing but broke the first level /k/page

any help would be great.

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

i've found the solution by adding that extra line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

hope it works for who needed to do that.

best.